# Apache running as a daemon so it starts automatically when Ubuntu server boots

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

How do I start Apache automatically when Ubuntu server boots up?

I installed it from source because I like to run the latest stuff. I've found you can't always trust Aptitude to have the latest.

Answer (score 3):

This should be the default behavior with the package in Ubuntu Server.

If for some reason it's not working, try the following command:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache defaults
```

This will create the symlinks needed for Apache's init scripts to be called at boot.

Comment: but I installed it from source because I like to run the latest stuff. Can't alwats trust the aptitude to have the latest I've found

Comment: If using apache2, substitute 'apache2' for 'apache'

Comment: In the case of installing for source, you need to create and install the init scripts. Many times these are distro specific!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Apache via `aptitude`, it should have installed an init-Script (have a look at `/etc/init.d/`). Therefore, it should start automatically already.

However, you can run `sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults` to re-install the symlinks of the init-script.

Here is a **[nice article](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-manage-services-with-update-rc.d)** describing what it's all about.